# How to retrieve rows from table based on column value(0,1)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with multiple rows which will contain the data in the following manner

```
col1   col2
100  -  1
100  -  0
102  -  1
102  -  0
103  -  1
```

I need to write a query to fetch the row (103-1). Means the query should return rows that do not have corresponding pair of records(xxx-1,xxx-0).

Comment: do you have only two possible values for column `col2` ? i.e. 0 and 1??

Comment: I dont understand the question. Do you always want the row with 103 in it or do you want the maximum value for col1 or what determins what row you need to fetch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select col1, max(col2) as col2
from your_table
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) = 1
```

Comment: This sql does not return the whole row.

Comment: Now it does return both

Comment: This solution helped me solve my requirement.Thanks to Alen and also others for their answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from   your_table a
where  not exists (select 1
                   from   your_table b
                   where  b.col1 = a.col1 
                   and    b.col2 != a.col2)
```

Here is an example [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f1e6/4)

Answer (score 0):

if you have only two possible values for column col2, as 1 and 0 then you can use following query to accomplish the above question -

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE col1 IN (SELECT col1 FROM your_table 
                GROUP BY col1 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col2) = 1)
```

as you want full columns (col1 and col2) in your output you can use `IN` in your query.

Comment: Should be `WHERE col1 IN`